# Why do we need default export in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I know there are two kinds of exports, one is named default and other is the default export.

```
// utils.js
const addOne = (a) => a+1;
export default addOne;
export const subOne = (a) => a- 1;

//app.js
import plusOne, {subOne} from './utils.js'
```

I am so confused about why we need a default export, it just can use only once.
The only reason is the named export provide the name locally, and the default export can rename.
However, if we have namely demand, maybe we need to use it repeatedly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default import isn't required. You can use named exports all you want. In your case, when you're exporting a bunch of utility functions, it would likely be better to use named exports. However, if you need to export just one function, usually a class, a default export is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Based off personal experience I can think of one practical real-world example where you'd have both a named export *and* a default export, and that's when you come to test a React component that's wrapped in a higher-order component.

```
class Hello extends Component {
  //
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```

If you're testing this component you'll run into all kinds of problems if you try and import the default export from this file. So instead you need to export just the component instead, and you can use a named export for that:

```
export class Hello extends Component {
  //
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```